# Log-periodic power law model: is it a continuous or discrete-time process?

Tags: time-series, finance

Are the log-periodic power law models used to predict financial market crashes continuous or discrete-time processes?

Comment: Could you add a reference to the Log-periodic power law for those (such as me) that are unfamiliar with it?

Comment: I believe the OP is referring to the work of the [in]famous Didier Sornette.

Comment: Yeah sorry, heres a reference https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9907270v1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The model is continuous in t, but you can use is as an approximation (with discrete prices as inputs) without adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

The log distribution of returns is $$\frac{1}{2\gamma}\text{sech}\left[\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\gamma}\right)\right]$$ when bankruptcy, mergers and the budget constraint are ignored.  I think the actual shocks in Sornette are actually liquidity shocks and because the bid-ask spread is ignored in most modelling, it looks like changes of underlying volatility. There is enough empirical data to support the issue that I think a careful study needs done.  Also, modeling things in logs is a bit more difficult than to do so in raw form.  We don't use punch cards anymore.  No one buys log(3 shares) +log($7/share).

You should treat them as continuous.  Do note that as you add variables to the distribution above, that you do not add covariates.  The distribution involved lacks anything resembling a covariance matrix.  $\gamma$ just turns into $\gamma'$.